# Can't connect to a wireless network in Arch Linux netctl

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, internet

I just installed arch linux on my laptop. 
But after rebooting, I can't connect to the internet. 
Wi-fi is the only available connection to me. 
I used the command wifi-menu then after choosing my wifi and entering my passkey, I still can't connect to the internet.

This is the error I got:

> Job for netctl@wlp6s0\x2dWifi.service failed. See 'systemctl status netctl@wlp6s0\x2dWifi.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

This the output after running systemctl status netctl@wlp6s0\x2dWifi.service

> netctl@wlp6s0\x2dWifi.service - Networking for netctl profile wlp6s0x2dWifi 
>  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service; static 
>   Active: inactive (dead) 
>   Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)

Please help. I tried to follow the wiki for netctl but it doesn't work. Maybe i just missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the `wpa_actiond` package installed.  The service you want to start is `netctl-auto@interface.service` Replacing interface with the name of your interface.  Based on your question, that would be `wlp6s0`

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all netctl-related systemd services, then use wifi-menu -o to generate a profile then type the following:

netctl enable *yourprofile*

It should work :) but im not sure...